# How to deal with "ERROR: Can't combine" when using Stata data read into R with haven?

Tags: r, stata, r-haven

I am having trouble working with Stata data that I have read into R. The data seems to be read in okay, and then is a tbl data.frame haven data class. However, when I try to do things like subset it, I get an error. Can anybody help?

```
data <- read_stata("/Users/..../Desktop/SOM.dta") 
data_stockholm <- subset(data, areg == "1")
Error: Can't combine `..1` <character> and `..2` <double>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Do you have labeled data? Several people have filed similar issues on `haven`s GitHub page. A possible fixed was released on GitHub only a week ago, but it's not on CRAN yet. You could try to download the development version and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Column **areg** of **data_stockholm** appears to be of type double (numeric) while you `subset` for something of type character `=="1"`. You could convert areg after importing or (probably) set variable types upon `read_stata`. Edit: unless this is a `haven` issue as @jpiversen notes.

Comment: @I_O I believe the problem is with `read_stata()`, not `subset()` due to the error message being similar to errors reported by others on GH. Also, `subset()` typically handles different classes well, e.g.: `subset(mtcars, cyl == "4")`.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I'm not sure if the data is labelled, but I think so - class of data$areg comes up as "haven_labelled". Would it be best to convert the data after reading it into R, or to try using the fix for the haven package?